# Android app that identifies an incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make an app that makes and receives phone calls and sms messages
The outgoing part works great.
I use broadcast receiver to catch the incoming call.
When i'm trying to debug it, it doesn't enther the onReceive function on an incoming call.

This is our manifest.xml

```
    <receiver android:name=".MYPhoneStateListener"
       android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999999"> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action> 
    </intent-filter> 

</receiver> 

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

this is the broadcast receiver:

```
    public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) 
    {
        Log.d("incoming", "incoming");
    }
}
```

}

What is the problem?
Is there any other way to impliment a call receiver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the receiver to match what you have defined on the Manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name=".CallBroadcastReceiver"
       android:exported="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to implement your phone listener like:

```
public class PhoneListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    @Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    }

}
```

The state can be:  TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING, TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE

In the broadcast receiver you register the listener :

```
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)    ctx.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```